# Why do I get 401 for static fies when using Express with React.js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, iis, reverse-proxy

**The Setup:**

- Node.js server with express runs on localhost:3000 (has a ldap session to active directory) and uses SSO with the package `node-expose-sspi`
- IIS Reverse Proxy runs on localhost:80 and redirects to the node server localhost:3000
- in Development a React Dev server on port localhost:3001 with a proxy in the `package.json`

**The Problem**:

I have a node express server that serves the build folder from my react app:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build")));


app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
});
```

The react app itself is just a simple hello world example. But when I go to my server through reverse proxy: http://myservername the page opens but I see this error in the console:

> GET http://myserver/static/js/2.d0df15ed.chunk.js net::ERR_ABORTED 401 (Unauthorized)

The page loads.

I have a test route called `/api/me`. This route just gets the user from SSO (single sign on) and returns it as json.

Now I have 3 different scenarios:

- The client just calls this api With simple fetch request and then says `<p>Hello {username}</p>` ==> It just shows "Hello" and the 401 for static files: **When I then open the path to the static file in the Browser directly, it works!**
- When I open the route directly in the browser I get the json I expected
- When I open the route on the react dev server (localhost:3001) I get "Hello <myusername" => so t his works too.

**I logged the webserver with procmon and this is what I found:**

[image]

I server my app in node like that:

`app.use( "/", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html")) );`

So the path can't be found because the path is not correct it should be AttractiveDirectory\client\build\static... `

Maybe that is where the error resides?

Now I really don't know how I can solve this. I looked through the logs on the reverse but nothing informative. So in some weird way the authentication doesn't work when using fetch on the client it seems. But why do I also get a 401 even when opening the site and only for the static files?

Do I made mistakes on the `express.static` side of things?

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that the root directory of the website has been granted full access to the `IUSR` account.
[image]
Besides, try to configure the `IIS URL Rewrite` extension in the root directory of your project.
Adding a `webconfig` file containing the below content.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
     <system.webServer>
     <rewrite>
     <rules>
     <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url=".*" />
     <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
     <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
     <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
     <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
     </conditions>
     <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
     </rule>
     </rules>
     </rewrite>
     </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Note: Before applying the above changes please install the URL Rewrite extension.
https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite
At last, check the below links for details.
https://gist.github.com/maxan/0d124ed677ebe41e1aeaf4a9e1e6aa45
https://medium.com/@mateioprea/setting-up-a-react-app-with-react-router-in-iis-71cb86aee376
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.